# How to not call every page "page.tsx" in Next.js 13 (App Router)

Tags: next.js, next.js13

**TLDR: Is there a way to not name everything `page.tsx`?**

I'm using Next.js 13 with the App Router for a new project. Based on the naming conventions outlined in the new [file naming convention](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure), my app folder structure now looks like this:

```
.
├── ...
│   ├── ...
│   │   └── page.tsx
│   ├── ...
│   │   └── page.tsx
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   │   └── route.ts
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   │   ├── [id]
│   │   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   │   │   │   └── route.ts
│   │   │   │   └── route.ts
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   │   ├── [id]
│   │   │   │   └── route.ts
│   │   │   └── route.ts
│   │   └── ...
│   │       └── [key]
│   │           └── route.ts
│   ├── layout.tsx
│   ├── ...
│   │   └── page.tsx
│   ├── ...
│   │   ├── [key]
│   │   │   └── page.tsx
│   │   └── page.tsx
│   ├── ...
│   │   ├── [key]
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   │   │   └── [id]
│   │   │   │       └── page.tsx
│   │   │   ├── page.tsx
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   │       └── page.tsx
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   │   └── page.tsx
│   │   └── page.tsx
│   ├── ...
│   │   └── page.tsx
│   └── ...
│       └── page.tsx
├── ...
│   ├── layout.tsx
│   ├── ...
│   │   └── page.tsx
│   ├── page.tsx
│   └── ...
│       └── page.tsx
├── ...
│   └── page.tsx
├── favicon.ico
├── globals.css
├── layout.tsx
```

How can I avoid having 16x `page.tsx` and 6x `route.ts`?

Especially the `page.tsx` files are irritating. Since I'm using server components, the pages contain a lot more logic that I would have previously put in an API. but I look at my VSCode tabs and everything is just `page.tsx`.

I find myself switching tabs and trying to find the main function name to figure out which page this is, which feels suboptimal.

Comment: [Nope](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#pages).

Comment: Rely on a better system to navigate between files, specifically fuzzy searching/opening files by path instead. I have personally disabled tabs entirely and navigate using the outlined approach to not get lost.